# Error Connecting to SSL - Delphi 7 Indy 9

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm trying to POST to a https Web service from Delphi 7. Initially the error was "Unable to Load SSL library". So placed ssleay32.dll & libeay32.dll (from indy_openssl096k.zip in https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/) in the folder containing my executable.

Now the error is "Error connecting to SSL". In the exception, I also used WhichFailedToLoad() function and below is also reported
"Failed To Load: EVP_md5 X509_digest X509_NAME_hash"

From different sites, I could understand, above functions is part of libeay32.dll. But why is this still reported as FailedToLoad ?

I saw suggestions that updating to Indy10 ca solve this. But the applications I'm working on uses Indy functions on large number of modules and I don't want to cause any issues if Indy update fails. Is there anyway to resolve this error with Indy9. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have been trying to find out a solution for the past few days and can't get one. Could someone kindly help me please ?

My Code

```
      Protocol := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      try
        jsonToSend := TStringList.create;
        Id_HandlerSocket := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.create(nil);
        Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
        Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
        Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
        Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
        try
           jsonToSend.Add('{"Branch":"' + branch + '", "Country":"' + country + '"}');
           Protocol.IOHandler := Id_HandlerSocket;
           Protocol.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
           Protocol.Request.Accept := '*/*';
           Protocol.Post(ServerURL,jsonToSend);
        except
          on E:EIdOSSLConnectError do
          begin
            showmessage(E.Message);
            showmessage('Failed to Load: ' + IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.WhichFailedToLoad);
          end;
        end;
      finally
        Protocol.Destroy;
        Id_HandlerSocket.Free;
        jsonToSend.Destroy;
      end;
```

Comment: Indy9 is old and obsolete now. And it seems that you are already know the answer to your question :)

Comment: Try running this again, but using sslvTSLv1_2. Also try setting a .CipherList. The only reason I am saying "try" is because it was only through trial-and-error that I was able to successfully use SSL in my Indy applications.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.......sslvTLSv1_2 won't work in my code. On compilation, it reports this method as undeclared identifier. Below are the SSL/TLS versions in my IdSSLOpenSSL  ```TIdSSLVersion = (sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1);```  Is there anyway to enable sslvTLSv1_2 to use it as the method

Comment: Indy 9 simply does not support TLS 1.1+ (or OpenSSL versions beyond 0.9.6. Or even *official* OpenSSL DLLs, the DLLs it uses are *customized* for Indy's use). You MUST upgrade to Indy 10 to use *official* OpenSSL DLLs up to 1.0.2, with TLS 1.1/1.2 (support for OpenSSL 1.1.x and TLS 1.3 is in progress at this time).

Comment: *Ararat Synapse* is old, but supports OpenSSL 1.1 - as per https://sourceforge.net/p/synalist/feature-requests/19/#51f0 I have successfully used it with Delphi 7.

Comment: Why is that the functions - EVP_md5 X509_digest X509_NAME_hash are not loading correctly, even after I have downloaded the correct dll files from https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/...........Could this be a reason for the Error connecting to SSL message ?

Comment: I just checked inside libeay32.dll and it has the functions - EVP_md5 X509_digest X509_NAME_hash in them. But can't figure out why they are being reported as Failed to Load

Comment: @SanyoAlexis Remy already gave you several clues. You need to use specific dll's with Indy9 (no I don't know where to get them) and you have to target TLS 0.9.6 or lower). Even then, it might not work, as you're in a time-machine that's earlier than 2004. A solution is to work with Indy 10 where you need SSL. If you don't want side affects with your existing Indy9 code, then make a DLL that uses Indy10 and call that DLL  from your Delphi 7/Indy9 code where you need it...